# This code is telling me that the id variable is undefined

Tags: php

This code is telling me that the $id variable is undefined. I already initialized it as a superglobal in the code but its still saying that its not initialized

```
 $id = $_POST['ID];

 $dbc =  mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $query = "DELETE FROM guitar_wars WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Why is it telling me that the id variable is undefined? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: `$id = $_POST['ID'];` try this

Comment: @Irfan That would fix the syntax error in the post, but not an undefined variable error. I'm assuming there was a mistake when pasting the code here.

Comment: Hey Irfan. Thanks for your help. The code still didnt work but I'm working on it. The problem with the code is elsewhere.

Comment: $query = "DELETE FROM guitar_wars WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1"; Is there something wrong with this code?